# Uptime / Downtime Production Batch Report via SSRS SQL Server 2012 Updated

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, uptime, downtime

I am working on another report using `SSRS` via `Visual Studio 2010`. I am a rookie with SQL but things are starting to make sense as the weeks go on.

Purpose is to create a report that displays the `Batch up time / downtime` calculated from the `timestamps` taken from a SQL server database. The time stamp is represented as a date/time input, an example, `2018-02-09 14:43:29.193`.

There are 4 Event ID's 1-4 that must be met to trigger a time stamp in the database. Each batch has it's own 3 digit integer ID.

```
1-Batch Start, Not running production, but system is initiated. (Down)
2-Production Start, Running production (Up Time)
3-Production Stop, Machine is running, but not producing (Down)
4-Batch Stop, Production complete. (Down)
```

The difference between,

```
2&1 = Downtime
4&1 = Downtime
2&3 = Up time
If 4 is after 2 = Up time
If 4 is after 3 = Downtime
```

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBsSb.jpg)

I have done my best with this report with limited knowledge, and in the report I have created parameters to choose dates for the report, along with asking the user to pick the Batch ID along with Batch 1-4 Event's, however I am not sure how to tackle the calculated fields.

Below is the SQL code,

```
 /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1000 
    [Productio_CrtNo]
  , [BatchEvent_ID]
  , [BatchEvent_TIME]
  , [Operator_ID]
  , [DieRolls_ID]
  , [Batch_ID]
  , [NoOfPockets]
  , [WetCapsulesWeight]
FROM [SCM_DataCollecion].[dbo].[ProductionTable]
```

[Current Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvSi3.jpg)

I have been reading up on pivoting tables and I think this may be the way to go in calculated the `up / downtime`, however I need a bit of help on this part.

Thanks again

Comment: Was there a question?

Comment: Hey, my question is what is the best way to calculate the down / uptime based on the data set.  I would like to add in either a calculated field which outputs the downtime/uptime in seconds for a specific batch, and or have a drop down parameter which asks the user based off of this chosen batch to select uptime/downtime or both.  Sorry if it's confusing, it's confusing me as well.

Comment: A better way to explain this would be to show desired result with sample data

Comment: You should also update your question to include your question.

Comment: Hi, I'm running SQL server 2012 standard edition. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 ways I could think of to solve this.

1. Use a ranking in the SQL based on the 3 digit id number
2. Use a Pivot in the SQL based on the event id
3. Use a matrix to do the pivot and perform the calculations in the report.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback.  I included my SQL query along with how the report currently looks.  Thanks again, all the best